# Question on inner products and expansion in bases

Tags: linear-algebra

> In Euclidean $\Bbb R^3$, the vectors $\mathbf b_1 = (1,1,1)^T,$ $\mathbf b_2 = (-2,1,1)^T$, and $\mathbf b_3 = (0,1,-1)^T$ are orthogonal. Use the inner product to write $\mathbf x = (-3,7,2)^T$ as a linear combination of $\mathbf b_1,\mathbf b_2$, and $\mathbf b_3$.

[picture of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ4um.jpg)

Can someone help me answer this question on inner products?

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their problems. For example, what are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Let $W=\text{Span} \{ \mathbf{b}_1, \mathbf{b}_2, \mathbf{b}_3 \}$. Recall that the orthogonal projection $\text{proj}_W ( \mathbf{x})$ of $\mathbf{x}$ onto $W$ is the vector in $W$ closest to $\mathbf{x}$. In particular this means that if $\mathbf{x} \in W$, we have $\text{proj}_W ( \mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}$. Since $\{ \mathbf{b}_1, \mathbf{b}_2, \mathbf{b}_3 \}$ is an orthogonal basis for $W$, we have

\begin{align*}
\text{proj}_W ( \mathbf{x}) & =\frac{\mathbf{b}_1 \cdot \mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{b}_1 \cdot \mathbf{b}_1}\mathbf{b}_1+\frac{\mathbf{b}_2 \cdot \mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{b}_2 \cdot \mathbf{b}_2}\mathbf{b}_2+\frac{\mathbf{b}_3 \cdot \mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{b}_3 \cdot \mathbf{b}_3}\mathbf{b}_3 \\
&= 2 \mathbf{b}_1+\frac{5}{2} \mathbf{b}_2 \frac{5}{2} \mathbf{b}_3 \\
&= \mathbf{x}
\end{align*}

I have omitted the arithmetic here so as not to deter attention from the idea. However, the calculations are simple to do by hand and may be checked using MATLAB or something similar.

Comment: It's really interesting how this answer was downvoted. Can the person who downvoted explain themselves? This looks perfectly reasonable to me.